# Are questions about microfabrication / clean-room processes on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

On one hand, most of clean-room processes (etching, thin films etc) are related to electrical engineering. On the other hand, organics are becoming popular.

Comment: Give it a try.  I don't think that it should be off-topic.

Comment: You probably won't get an answer right away. My one and only E.SE (not EE.SE) question is still unanswered prolly because nuclear engineers don't come around often. You get the idea, I think.

Comment: Also, a lot of the process information is trade secret.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff  We've got active members who currently work in semiconductor industry.  Chances that the question will end up in front of a person with the right kind of insight are not too slim.  Although, they may or may not be in a position to talk about it, like Matt said.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: I know, I just a gave small bounty to one of them :-)

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: Your question there is about specific theoretical things that have not many people in the world worked with. clean room stuff usually though is well understood and a lot of people work with.

Comment: @NickAlexeev [posted](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193106/how-can-i-deposit-metallic-electrodes-on-a-temperature-sensitive-wafer). can you please create the tags clean-room and microfabrication?